# DefaultBrowser from Registry doesn't work

Tags: c#, browser, shell, process.start

I'm trying to open a url in the default browser. Obviously I thought that Shell Exec will open it in the default browser but it doesn't.

Then I tried explicit:

```
Process.Start(GetDefaultBrowserPath(), "http://stackoverflow.com");

private static string GetDefaultBrowserPath()
{
    string key = @"htmlfile\shell\open\command";
    RegistryKey registryKey =
    Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(key, false);
    // get default browser path
    return ((string)registryKey.GetValue(null, null)).Split('"')[1];
}
```

It always returns Internet Explorer but not my default which is Firefox. I tried it on several computers...

I don't care which way to call the link in the default browser, but it has to be the **default**

Comment: When you say it's your default, are you sure that if you create a new .html file on your desktop and double click it, it in fact does open in Firefox?

Comment: yes, I just tried. new .html file on desktop, double click and open in Firefox.

Comment: `Process.Start("http://stackoverflow.com");` works on my machine (opens Chrome).

Comment: If you just use a URL as the process location parameter, the OS will automatically use the default browser to navigate to that URL.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried just running:

```
Process.Start("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

My test application (below) opens the site in my default browser:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ProcessStartSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process.Start("http://stackoverflow.com");
        }
    }
}
```

In other words, let the operating system do the heavy work of working out what the users default browser is for you! =)

Answer (score 1):

Just Try this :)

```
Process.Start("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

And if you want to find your default browser you should open `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command\default` key.

Please pay attention "http" not "htmlFile"

EDIT:

CODE:

```
RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"http\shell\open\command", false);
string value = registryKey.GetValue("").ToString();
```

Comment: RegistryKey registryKey =
    Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("\http\shell\open\command\default", false);
but now registryKey  is null

Answer (score 0):

Windows will start the default browser on the user's system for you automatically if you just specify the URL to open:

```
Process.Start("http://www.google.com/");
```

No need for any fancy Registry trickery, unless you are trying to ascertain *which* browser is set as the default.